# C# System.Drawing.Rectangle into Ellipse on System.Drawing.Bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap, face-detection

I have a facial recognition library working that gives me an array of rectangle. Right now I'm using this way to draw the rectangle.

```
foreach (Rectangle box in boxes)
{
     for (int x = box.X; x <= box.X + box.Width; x++)
     {
          for (int y = box.Y; y <= box.Y + box.Height; y++)
          {
               outputbmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Red));
          }
     }
}
```

[image]

I'm looking for something as simple as:

```
Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse(box); //cast rect to ellipse
outputbmp.DrawEllipse(ellipse);
```

which will look something more like:

[image]

where the outline of the ellipse touching the rectangle corners.

Based on the approach I used above, it is easy to draw a rectangle but for ellipse, it would require me to know all the points in the ellipse. Just wonder if there's anything to make my life easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to draw directly to the bitmap, there is a higher level object you can create, called a [Graphics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage(v=vs.110).aspx) that gives you all kinds of wonderful drawing tools. It will also be significantly faster than drawing pixel by pixel.

You can create a `Graphics` for a given `Bitmap` by calling `Graphics.FromImage` and passing in the bitmap.  You must remember ti call `Dispose` on the Graphics though, or it will leak resources.

Once you have a `Graphics` instance for your bitmap you can call `DrawEllipse` and pass in the bounds exactly as you expect.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt06kxfd(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private void DrawEllipseInt(Graphics g)
{
    // Create pen.
    Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

    // Create location and size of ellipse.
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int width = 200;
    int height = 100;

    // Draw ellipse to screen.
    g.DrawEllipse(blackPen, x, y, width, height);
}
```